# 'InvalidPipelineOperator' with $lookup when adding .toArray()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation

I'm new to MongoDB, and working with aggregation. Here goes:

I have two collections 'video_card' and 'vendors'. I am fetching a video card document from the collection with the following structure:

```
_id:ObjectId(x),
vendorList:
    0: ID1;
    1: ID2;
```

I am trying to do a join between this document and **this** vendor collection:

```
_id: id:ObjectId(y)
name: "Amazon"
```

My aggregate is as follows so far:

```
const products = await db
.collection("video_card")
.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      mappedVendors: {
        $map: {
          input: "$vendorList",
          as: "vendorName",
          in: {
            $lookup: {
              from: "vendors",
              localField: "vendorList",
              foreignField: "name",
              as: "VendorNames"
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

This returns a cursor object. However, when I attach .toArray() to the end of this, I get a code:168 'InvalidPipelineOperator'. Why is this?

To clarify, my intent is to return the data with vendorList ids swapped with names.

Comment: See [aggregate Cursor Behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html#behavior): *In the mongo shell, if the cursor returned from the db.collection.aggregate() is not assigned to a variable using the var keyword* - maybe try without `const`

Answer (score 0):

To follow up, I realized that my foreignField in the $lookup was incorrect, and changed it to _id. I hope this helps other people learning aggregate functions.